# Python class (object) has no attribute

Tags: python, class, methods, pyqt

I'm a beginner in python classes and i have a little problem with this code (it's a pyqt code). The function *globalprogress* is called from another file but when he call the function *UpdateBar*, my computer keeps telling me that "*Ui_IA object has no attribute 'progression'*" but that's not true.

Does somebody knows if I did something wrong here? 
Thank you.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_IA(object):

    def setupUi(self, IA):
        IA.setObjectName("IA")
        IA.resize(931, 570)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(IA)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.progression = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralWidget)
        self.progression.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 450, 831, 61))
        self.progression.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progression.setObjectName("progression")

    def UpdateBar(self):
        self.progression.setValue(percentage)

def globalprogress(number):
    global percentage
    UIIA = Ui_IA()
    percentage = int(number)
    UIIA.UpdateBar()
```

Comment: You have to call the setupUI method that allows you to fill in the widgets, I recommend you check the docs: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code

Answer (score 0):

the function setupUI(), in which the progression attribute is set, is not called by default. You can use `__init__()`, which will automatically run as soon as the class is instantiated (i.e. an object of the class is made), or force setupUI() to run within the globalprogress() function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `setupUi()` on your `UIIA` object before executing `UpdateBar()`.

Comment: How can I call setupUi() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_IA(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(931, 570)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")

        self.progression = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralWidget)
        self.progression.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 450, 831, 61))
        self.progression.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progression.setObjectName("Progression")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)    

    def UpdateBar(self, MainWindow, percentage=0):
        self.progression.setValue(percentage)
        self.progression.show()

def globalprogress(number):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_IA()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    ui.UpdateBar(MainWindow, number) 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    globalprogress(55)
```

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks I will try this solution